# PHP 4 and json_decode

Tags: php, json

So I came across this bit of php code:

```
<?php
$long_url = "http://example.com";
$bit_ly = "http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten?login=your_user_name&apiKey=R_4868094cb43d09fb&longUrl=" . $long_url . "&format=json";
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($bit_ly));
$short_url = $response->data->url;
?>
```

I tested this locally and it worked great, once I uploaded it onto my server, I noticed iI was getting some errors, come to find out, jason_decode became standard from PHP 5.2 and my server is running PHP 4 and does not work.

Is there a simple way, without compiling a new version of PHP or adding a library to get this to work with PHP 4?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If your server is running PHP4, something is wrong.  Please speak to your sysadmin about the issue.  **PHP4 is no longer supported** and has not been updated for years.  You should not be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this this article, probably this can help you

http://blueberryware.net/2008/10/28/php4-json-encode-decode

http://www.epigroove.com/posts/97/how_to_use_json_in_php_4_or_php_51x

Comment: thanks for the links!, I ended up using the 1st link to get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

Check out the [json](http://www.json.org/) website.

You could use the [PECL json package](http://pecl.php.net/package/json)

Or [Blueberryware](http://blueberryware.net/2008/10/28/php4-json-encode-decode)

Or if you are using [codeigniter](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/99120/)

Comment: What if the PHP version is lower than 4.3.0?

Comment: @Maxbester Then it's time to find a new webhost (php 4.3.0 was released at the end of 2002)

Answer (score 0):

The best two json_decode() and json_encode() implementation you'll ever find for PHP4 with elegant degradation when your script is used with PHP5:

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/05/using-json-encode-and-json-decode-in-php4/
(also read the comments)

and this (same with a few twists):
http://www.epigroove.com/posts/97/how_to_use_json_in_php_4_or_php_51x